# Ionic 3 - Vibration is not working but the sound is

Tags: ionic-framework, push-notification, ionic3

I'm using ionic 3 to build an application and now, i'd like to send some notifications to the users.

When i received a notification the sound is working but the vibration no.

I have tested in two different devices.

```
    var serviceAccount = require(constantsManager.FirebaseKey);

    if (!admin.apps.length) {
        admin.initializeApp({
            credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
            databaseURL: constantsManager.FirebaseDataUrl
        });
    }

    var messageToSend = {
        android: {
            priority: constantsManager.FirebaseNotificationPriority,
            notification: {
                title: title,
                body: message,
                sound: 'default',
            }
        },
        topic: topic
    };

    admin.messaging().send(messageToSend)
        .then(function (response) { console.log('Push success: ' + JSON.stringify(response)); })
        .catch(function (error) { console.log('Push Error: ' + error); });
```

And in ionic 3 i have:

```
pushSetup() {
const options: PushOptions = {
  android: {
    senderID: Constants.NOTIFICATION_SENDER_ID,
    sound: Constants.NOTIFICATION_SOUND,
    vibrate: Constants.NOTIFICATION_VIBRATE,
    topics: Constants.NOTIFICATION_TOPICS,
    icon: Constants.NOTIFICATION_ICON
  },
  ios: {
    sound: Constants.NOTIFICATION_SOUND,
    topics: Constants.NOTIFICATION_TOPICS,

  }
};

const pushObject: PushObject = this.push.init(options);

pushObject.on('notification').subscribe((notification: any) => this.showMessageToUser(notification.title + " " + notification.message));

pushObject.on('registration').subscribe((registration: any) => console.log('Device registered', registration));

pushObject.on('error').subscribe(error => console.error('Error with Push plugin', error));

}
```

Any advice?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This resolved my issue:

```
var messageToSend = {
        data: {
            title: title,
            body: message,
            priority: constantsManager.FirebaseNotificationPriority
        },

        topic: topic
    };
```